# Get result from a table with a condition and then use the result of it to check another condition in the same table and get the output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which consists of multiple columns.

Table consists of data like

| Group no | Maxtime | Updatedtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A22 | 20221502 | 20221702 |
| A22 | 20212502 | 20221702 |
| A22 | 20212502 | 20221702 |

I query that table with a condition like

```
Select Group no from cnt where maxtime<=updatedtime
```

The output comes `A22`

Now I want to use this output to query the same table again and get the count of A22 which is 3 with a condition in where clause where I use other columns of the table.

Something like

```
Select count(group no)
From cnt
Where (effdate<candate)
```

Effdate and candate are columns of the same table.

Comment: why can't you combine them into one query?
Select COUNT(Group no) from cnt where maxtime<=updatedtime AND effdate<candate

Comment: Because then it shows group count as 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want this: count the rows with effdate < candate for each group_no for which exists a row with maxtime <= updatedtime.

```
Select group_no, count(*)
from cnt
where effdate < candate
and group_no in (select group_no from cnt where maxtime <= updatedtime)
group by group_no
order by group_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` to get the counts of each group. And combine both conditions with `AND`.

```
SELECT group_no, COUNT(*)
FROM cnt
WHERE maxtime <= updatedtime
AND effdate < candate
GROUP BY group_no
```

Comment: Shows the group count as 1 where it should be 3

Comment: Please add `effdate` and `candate` to the sample data. And show more than one `group_no` so we can see the pattern.

Comment: The solution above has worked correctly.

Comment: The question is still poorly written because it doesn't clearly explain what you're trying to accomplish.